# Wordpress get_posts with image

Tags: image, wordpress

So, I want to display titles and excerpt in line with images?   How can I do that?

```
<div id="treia_box" style="height:350px; width:350px;"> 
    <?php
    add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'category' => 29 );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"<?php the_title('<h7>', '<h7>'); ?></a></h2>
    <?php $size = array(75,75);
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, $size)?>
    <h6><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h6> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, $size)` would be correct , but :

1 - you need to specify $size , e.g. :  "large" , "thumbnail" "my_custom_size"

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'thumbnail');     // Thumbnail
get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'medium');        // Medium resolution
get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'large');         // Large resolution

get_the_post_thumbnail($id, array(100,100) ); // Other resolutions
```

2 - It will work only if the user (you) define a post thumbnail (featured - image when creating a post)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best way to do it:

```
$posts = get_posts(
    // ...
);
foreach( $posts as $p ){
    global $post;
    $post = $p;
    setup_postdata($post);
    $post->image = (object)[
        "sizes" => my_get_image_size_links()
    ];
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```